# Using env variable github.ref_name doesn't give me branch name

Tags: github, github-actions

When I use in my workflow `github.ref_name` it doesn't provide me a branch name from where I triggered this workflow. I get `16/merge`. Why? When I use `github.ref_type` I clearly see that my ref type is `branch` so why I don't get branch name?

Also it's showing when I use `$GITHUB_REF` or `git symbolic-ref HEAD` (and separating `refs/heads/` off). Ah and I tried `github.event.push.ref` but it's not showing me anything.

How to get always branch name from where I triggered the workflow?

Comment: Note for a PR you can use `github.event.pull_request.head.ref` to get the branch name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For following code:

```
Run echo running on branch ${GITHUB_REF##*/} ${GITHUB_REF}
```

When your workflow runs becuase of push event you will get:

```
running on branch main refs/heads/main
```

But for pulr request event it would be:

```
running on branch merge refs/pull/3/merge
```

[Why's that?](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/GitHub-Maintaining-a-Project)

> If the repository is on GitHub and you have any Pull Requests that have been opened, you’ll get these references that are prefixed with refs/pull/. These are basically branches, but since they’re not under refs/heads/ you don’t get them normally when you clone or fetch from the server — the process of fetching ignores them normally.

You can also check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594658/git-refs-merge-vs-head-in-pull-request)