# Get PR branch from Git

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get git log details from my release pipeline but git command I am using can not find the PR branch

```
refs/pull/<number>/merge
```

I tried this
[Git refs merge vs head in pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594658/git-refs-merge-vs-head-in-pull-request)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the PR ID is correct? 78091 sounds extremely high

Comment: What about `git log -10 --no-merges pull/78091/merge`?

Comment: Could `--no-merges` switch be the problem? The refs/pull/../merge basically points to the merge commit, and if you omit merge commits with that switch, it simply can't be found