# how to check diff of a file compared to the previous commit on github action

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a file with a timestamp stored in it.
In order to check if that file has changed compared to the previous commit, I simply `git diff` on local, and then I parse the output:

```bash
  git diff --word-diff=porcelain HEAD~1 -- dev/tests/artifact_build_timestamp.info  > /tmp/timestamp-diff.txt || exit 2;
```

This is useful even when I have a new uncommited timestamp on the WD too.

But: on github actions this is not possible. When checking out, it is in detached mode and I can't compare against HEAD~1:

By using the `actions/checkout@v3` action this is what it performs (and I want it to perform). In order to have the full history I set the `fetch-depth: 0`

```
Checking out the ref
  /usr/bin/git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/pull/4/merge
  Note: switching to 'refs/remotes/pull/4/merge'.
```

I'm wondering what's the best way to compare against its previous commit. An idea I have is:

```
if [[ ! -z "$CI" ]]; then
  BRANCH_NAME=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF}
  git pull origin ${BRANCH_NAME} || exit 1;
  git diff --word-diff=porcelain origin/${BRANCH_NAME}~1 origin/${BRANCH_NAME} -- dev/tests/artifact_build_timestamp.info  > /tmp/timestamp-diff.txt || exit 2;
fi
```

But I don't know if it's safe on any case an action could be run, or even if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

By default `actions/checkout` only checks out a single commit, making the checkout shallow.

If you want one additional (previous) commit set the `fetch-depth` input to `1`:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 1
```

If you want the entire history (all commits) set the `fetch-depth` input to `0`:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches).

> When checking out, it is in detached mode

That's irrelevant. Detached `HEAD` or on branch — if you have 2 commits you can run `git diff HEAD~`. If you only have 1 commit you cannot — there is no `HEAD~`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use `fetch-depth: '0'`, you're totally right! The point is that the detached mode is of a new branch github creates in order to calculate the merging result after the PR `refs/remotes/pull/4/merge`, hence HEAD~1 couldn't work the way I want I guess. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594658/git-refs-merge-vs-head-in-pull-request#63595981